# MVC Web app to get Outlook mail failing with unable to resolve remote name 'login.microsoftonline.com'

Tags: ssl, proxy, outlook, owin-middleware, azure-authentication

I created the example app of [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial)

It works fine when I am not connected to a vpn or work related network. Once I login it fails with the following error:

[image: Application Error]

I guess this has to do with the SSL certificates. I do have cert installed for the login.microsoftonline.com site:

[image: Certificate for microsoftonline]

Something must go wrong with the certificate or might it be a proxy issue? Is there anybody who can give me advise what to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem, it has to do with a proxy:

I added the following sites to my trusted sites list:

> https://*.microsoft.com
>       https://*.microsoftonline.com
>       https://*.microsoftonline-p.com
>       https://*.outlook.com

I added the following to the web.config file of the proyect:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <module type = "<YourNameSpace>.MyProxy, <YourNameSpace>" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Then I added a new class with code for MyProxy:

```
namespace <YourNameSpace>
{
    public class MyProxy : IWebProxy
    {
        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get { return new NetworkCredential(@"<UserName>", @"<Password>", @"<Domain(optional)>"); }
            set { }
        }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            return new Uri("http://<YourProxy>:<Port>");
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```